# Probability of hitting tails

Tags: distributions, probability

I have 5 variables for 1000 observations. Given the data, I need to

1. Calculate probability of hitting top 5 pct in each of the distributions separately. For example, for the value of 123.45 I need to calculate how probable is that this vale is from the top 5pct.
2. Calculate probability that a particular observation (given with 5 values for each variables) will be in the tails of each of the distributions... In the same time
3. Calculate probability that a particular observation will hit at least one 5pct tail.

How would you go about this?

Comment: Do you have any information about the joint distribution of the five variables or are you trying to estimate it? If you specify a distribution, this problem reduces to simple calculations of areas under the joint density.

Comment: I don't have any info on joint distribution...

Comment: @Ryan I imagine 1000 observations would tell you *something* about the data distribution :-).

Comment: It's not market data. It's not any particular (know) statistical distribution. It looks like normal distribution with very fat right tail (all 5 variables)...

Answer (score -2):

so how you can tell is you should plot the quantiles of your data against the theoretical quantiles of the weibull distribution, t distribution, ect. If the quantiles lie on a 45 degree line, then the data is from that distribution.

if you have R you can use the fitdistr function that is part of the MASS library.  this will tell you the parameter values of your distribution so you can then use the density function of your distribution to get the probabilities.

If you dont have R i would download it cause this would be computationally taxing otherwise.

Comment: can you please be a little bit more precise? How do you suggest I get joint probability of all 5 vars being in top 5% and then probability of at least one hitting top 5%?

Comment: @Ryan How exactly does the t distribution apply here?

Comment: I have data for each variable. So my dataset has 5 columns and aprox. 1000 rows

Comment: btw. I think my distributions are closest to Weibull(1,1)

Comment: Yeah.. But, let's say that I have to work out solution for the case where I don't know distribution...

Comment: @user @cespinoza Characterizing the marginals does not solve the second and third problems, which address possible lack of dependence.

Comment: @whuber You are right. Do you have maybe idea how to tackle problems 2 and 3?

Comment: @user333 Yes, but there is a subtle difficulty that I'm not sure how to handle.  If you knew *a priori* what the 95th percentiles of the marginals were, you could answer (2) and (3) easily just by counting the cases among your observations (this is the usual Binomial theory).  The problem is that you must *estimate* those percentiles from the very same data.  It is valid to use these estimates and the Binomial theory to get answers, but (a) I'm not sure how good those answers are and (b) it is *not* valid to use the Binomial theory to come up with standard errors or confidence intervals.

Comment: @user333 There is literature on this.  Google `nonparametric "tolerance region"` to find some.  An early account, accessible on the Web, appears at http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/dfraser/documents/10.pdf.  A section in [a recent book](http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Tolerance-Regions-Applications-Computation/dp/0470380268) by Krishnamoorthy & Mathew might also address this question, but I haven't been able to read the entire section.

Comment: tnx. Will look into that.